# Terminate ExpressJS request

Tags: node.js, express

How would I end an Express 3 request?  res.end() certainly doesn't stop the processing.

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
  res.end();
  console.log('Still going, going...');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to `return`.  E.g.,

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
  return res.end();
  console.log('I will never run...');
```

`res.end()` simply completes and flushes the response to the client.  Just like any other action, however, that doesn't tell JavaScript to stop running so we need to explicitly `return` out of the function (although I might ask the question of why you would have code after flushing the response that you don't actually want to run...?).

Comment: Ah almost had it! I had res.send(500) followed by return res.end() and it looped forever - return res.send(500) gave me what I needed. To answer your question I am simply checking for the presence of some required variables (for an api feed) and wanted to just bail out rather than encapsulating the rest of the code in a condition loop.